# How to add two UILoader inside a UILoader and save the contents of the UILoader using actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, uiloader

I have been into a research these past hours in figuring out how to add a UILoader inside a UILoader and save all the contents of a UILoader. I have two instance of UILoader (loader_inner and loader_outer) and they are both placed manually using the UILoader component.
The code goes something like this:

```
loader_inner.load(new URLRequest("background_1.jpg"));
loader_outer.load(new URLRequest("rabbit.jpg"));
loader_outer.addChild(loader_inner);
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(loader_outer.width,loader_outer.height);
bitmapData.draw(loader_outer);
var jpgencoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
var mybyte:ByteArray = jpgencoder.encode(bitmapData);
var myfile:FileReference = new FileReference();
myfile.save(mybyte,"test.jpg");
```

The problem is during save, I can only see the a white image in file but not the two contents. I am expecting a background with a rabbit in the image file that is placed exactly on the two components drawn manually in the work space.

Comment: How did you manage to add a `UILoader` "inside" of another `UILoader`? EDIT: Nevermind, I see the call to `addChild`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UILoader.load` is an asynchronous action. As such, you are attempting to draw the loader to a bitmap before it has actually had a chance to load the images. You will need to listen for `COMPLETE` events on both inner and outer loaders:

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.Event;

loader_inner.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
loader_outer.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
loader_inner.load(new URLRequest("background_1.jpg"));
loader_outer.load(new URLRequest("rabbit.jpg"));
loader_outer.addChild(loader_inner);

function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void 
{
    // check to make sure that *both* loaders have fully loaded
    if(loader_inner.percentLoaded && loader_outer.percentLoaded)
    {
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(loader_outer.width,loader_outer.height);
        bitmapData.draw(loader_outer);
        var jpgencoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
        var mybyte:ByteArray = jpgencoder.encode(bitmapData);
        var myfile:FileReference = new FileReference();
        myfile.save(mybyte,"test.jpg"); 
    }
}
```